# Android Beacon Library and Update 6.0.1

Tags: android, bluetooth, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

Yesterday I updated my Samsung Galaxy S5 Neo to the new Android Version 6.0.1. Since then the beacons won't be detected anymore. It does connect the Beacon Service, Updates the scan perios, etc. but it doesn't find any beacons. 
Bluetooth is activated and the Beacon scanner of the Beacon Manifacturer still works fine (finds all the beacons). But not my app... It all worked before the new Android Update.

Comment: What version of Android were you on before the upgrade?

Comment: Must have been 5.1.1 I think API21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to check:

1. **Verify Location is enabled** in Settings -> Location.  This must be set to High Accuracy or Battery Saving.  If set to Device Only, it won't work.  Starting with Android 6, Location must be enabled to do bluetooth scans.
2. **Make sure your app has been granted location permission.**  Check Settings -> Apps -> Your App -> Permissions, and verify the Location slider is set to on.  Starting with Android 6, each app must dynamically request location access at runtime.  If your app doesn't have code to do this, you'll need to add it.  (Although it is possible to override in settings as described here.)
3. Make sure your app's manifest declares either FINE_LOCATION or COARSE_LOCATION in its declared permissions.
4. If the above don't help check LogCat (not just filtering on your application) for bluetooth errors.

See [here](https://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/09/29/is-your-beacon-app-ready-for-android-6.html) for more info on the above.

Comment: Point 2 it was indeed! I set the Permissions on the permission slider to "on" and it worked again. Wow thank you so much, you are a true hero! :)

Comment: Glad you found it.  Keep in mind that changing this in settings works, but few end-users will figure out to do that.  You'll need to update the app to dynamically request permissions as described in the link in my answer.

Comment: Yes I will do that later, but for testing it currently works for me. :)